# jQuery working in localhost but not when live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, localhost

I'm using the following code to animated a title in my slideshow. It is working fine in my localhost but as soon as I upload it to live it doesn't seem to be working.

All my files are linked properly I just can't see why this would be happening.

I wondered if anyone could see anything wrong with the code or may have a reason why this might be.

```
$(window).load(function () {

doIt();

function doIt(){
    $('#title1').fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $('#title1').addClass('animated title-pop');
})
$('#title1').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend 
animationend', function() {
$('#title1').delay(8200).fadeOut(2000, function() {doIt();});
});
};

doItTwo();

function doItTwo(){
    $('#title2').fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $('#title2').addClass('animated title-pop');
})
$('#title2').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend 
animationend', function() {
$('#title2').delay(8200).fadeOut(2000, function() {doItTwo();});
});
};

});
```

Comment: do you get some error in your console? F12 to open developer tools to see if you get some javascript errors.

Comment: Or you can also provide your site address.

Comment: if your code works in localhost then there is no problem with it. the problem is when u upload it to your live server. make sure all your references are valid and not blocked.

Comment: If it works locally most likely it is not a code problem but has to do with paths.  Make sure jQuery and your custom JS scripts file is actually being loaded on your live site.

Comment: I have lots of other things being controlled by the same file and they are working fine. I have two things with the CSS applied to it and they don't seem to be working when live despite them being in the main.css file. How would I know if all my references are valid?

Comment: I tried removing that script but nothings changed with the other element thats being affected so its not my script. I have a feeling it might be the CSS now but I can't understand why it would work locally and not live.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help i solved it - it was my css file i'd made a mistake when copying over some code and messed it up. Thanks for you all taking the time to help.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the correct path to your jQuery file on your live server.

Comment: The paths are all correct as I have other things working from that file.

Comment: Add a console.log message inside your window.load function to see if it's actually being called. If the message doesn't appear in your console, then it means jQuery isn't being loaded at all.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I checked the web developer console (Firebug on Firefox) and found there was a JavaScript error. The path to jQuery was set as `http` while my website is `https`, so the jQuery wasn't loading correctly.

After I set `http` to `https`, the script loaded perfectly.